# Google Analytics API output data in a readable format

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm using the [Embed API](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/) in order to display Google Analytics data using server-side authentication.
I've been able to display the graphs I needed but now I have a problem,
I'm trying to display the following table used by Google Analytics:

[image]

I've been able to display the same data but they're not readable as the one displayed by Analytics, for example the **Avg. Session Duration** should be represented in seconds but what I display is: 165.28275862068966

My question is, is there any way to request the correct data format to the Embed API or do I need to calculate them by myself?

An example of the query I call is this:

```
var dataChart5 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
query: {
  'ids': 'ga:***', // My ID
  'start-date': '31daysAgo',
  'end-date': 'yesterday',
  'metrics': 'ga:users,ga:percentNewSessions,ga:sessions,ga:bounceRate,ga:avgSessionDuration,ga:pageviews,ga:pageviewsPerSession',
  'prettyPrint':'true',
},
chart: {
  'container': 'chart-5-container',
  'type': 'TABLE',
  'options': {
    'width': '100%',
    'title': 'test'
  }
}
  });

   dataChart5.execute();
```

Comment: Have you checked the dimensions and metrics reference i think most of them a already calculated for you.

Comment: @DaImTo I've already checked but since this data is being shown all in the same table I can't find a way to display it the correct way (so there are going to be %, seconds but also normal numbers), if possible can you provide a link for these reference? Because from the docs I've found I wasn't able to display the data in the correct format

Comment: sorry misunderstood the question. Try that anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is returned in an raw format by the Google Analytics API

Lets look at [ga:avgsessionduration](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=session&jump=ga_avgsessionduration)

> The average duration of user sessions represented in total seconds.
>   Data type:  TIME

So the number you are seeing is 165.28275862068966 seconds.  If you want to see it like its displayed on the website

> 00:00:00

You are going to have to format it yourself.   The API returns its data in one format in the case of this one its total number of seconds.

Comment: Ok thanks! I was hoping for a method from the Embed API but I'll just parse it after the response before calling the execute method. May I ask you one last question? Do you know if there's any library or method from the chart API's in order to format the data?

Comment: The Embeded API just uses the core reporting API to fetch data so you are limited to what it returns.   I dont know of any method for formatting the data sorry.

Comment: I've opened an answer following this one, if you have time can you please read it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606704/google-embed-api-format-data-before-calling-execute Thank you very much :)

Comment: I am the one that +1 and stared it :)  Hoping someone will answer its a good question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an actual answer...

https://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/09/17/creating-a-custom-display-for-googles-analytics-embed-library

Example Node code...

```
const moment = require( "moment" );

function formatTime(str) {
    var dur = moment.duration(parseInt(str,10), 'seconds');
    var minutes = dur.minutes();
    var seconds = dur.seconds();
    return minutes + " minutes and " + seconds + " seconds";
}

console.log( formatTime( "165.282" ) );
```